# How to show data from component in slot?

Tags: vue.js

I have a lot of HTML, that is inserted in the slot. And I need to change this HTML from the data of the component. But I can't get data of the component

```vue
<template lang="pug">
.div
  slot
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: "mycomponent",
 data() {
  return {
    sizeblock: 0,
    activetab: 3
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

In html:

```pug
mycomponent.div
  nav(:style="{'min-height': sizeblock+'px'}")
    button(:class="{'active': activetab == index") 1
    button(:class="{'active': activetab == index") 2
    button(:class="{'active': activetab == index") 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `data` to `slot` and use it when it get replaced by parent

I am not familiar with `pug` templates so writing in normal template, hope you able to convert it.

So you will pass your data to slot and when you consume it you just receive it

```
<template lang="pug">
.div
  <slot :data="{ sizeblock, activetab}" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: "mycomponent",
 data() {
  return {
    sizeblock: 0,
    activetab: 3
  }
 }
}
</script>

mycomponent.div
 <template v-slot:default="{data}">
     nav(:style="{'min-height': data.sizeblock+'px'}")
    button(:class="{'active': data.activetab == index") 1
    button(:class="{'active': data.activetab == index") 2
    button(:class="{'active': data.activetab == index") 3
  </template>
```